# Unique algorithm on vectors c++

Tags: c++

I have a structure stored inside the vector. There are duplicate copies of the struct in the vector. Can i use the unique algorithm on the vector? but generally i see that unique s used oly on individual values in c++

Comment: Yes, as long as the vector is sorted. If you want more details, you need to add some code to your question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement a way to compare your structs (e.g. define the `<` (for sort) and `==` operators (for unique) or provide a comparator). You need to sort your vector using that and then apply unique.

Comment: The comparison between elements is performed by either applying the == comparison operator, or the template parameter `comp` between them.

Comment: @Naszta: True. I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out. He will still need the `<` for sorting.